# My Apps website gore not match the domain I thought I was getting

Tags: google-app-engine

Thank you for any help that you can get me. So on 8/19 I was able to get my website posted to the cloud and while it took some time, I was eventually able to get it hosted. The issue that I am having is that the domain I believe I got at start up is not the domain that is showing for my website.

So as you should be able to see, I just recently started a company. I got the warptechno.com domain. To my understanding I also purchased the URL for that. I built a simple website and posted it on the cloud. But the issue is that the URL that was created for the site once it completed it was warptechno.ue.r.appspot.com, this is a horrible naming and way to long. To my knowledge I should have been getting warptechno.com The app is doen in React . Not sure if I am doing something wrong or misunderstanding it.

Comment: You haven't got any DNS address records for the domain. Set them up according to the documentation.

Comment: HI and thank you very much. Which documentation should I be looking at to do this with? Looks like I need to setup hostname, type,TTL and data but unsure what to enter for these.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains

Comment: Thank you very much.......